# LINQ to find set difference based on a column

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists `Person` and `Product` with common, unique ID. I want get entries in `Product` whose IDs do not match the IDs in `Person`. What should be the LINQ query?

`List<Person>`:

```
ID    Name
1     Abc
3     Xyz
```

`List<Product>`:

```
ID    Price
3     400
5     150
```

Expected result - a list of type `Product`:

```
ID    Price
5     150
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var result = products.Where(p => !persons.Select(x => x.Id)
                                         .Contains(p.Id));
```

Comment: is there a `sql` like syntax for doing the same?

Answer (score 4):

```
var persionIDs = new HashSet<int>(persons.Select(person => person.ID));
IEnumerable<Product> invalidProducts = 
                 products.Where(product => !persionIDs.Contains(product.ID));
```

The use of a HashSet optimizes the lookup by person ID

Answer (score 3):

The short approach

```
products.Where(product => !persons.Any(p => p.ID == product.ID));
```

The more efficient approach using `Except` and `Join` which use `Sets` internally

```
from prod in products
join pID in products.Select(p => p.ID).Except(persons.Select(pers => pers.ID))
on prod.ID equals pID
select prod;
```